# Why is nothing logged?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make it so that a string gets logged in the console every time I click on a button. However, nothing is logged. Why so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function log_a_string_plz() {
    console.log("some string i want logged");
  }
  document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("my_wonderful_button").onclick = log_a_string_plz;
  }
  </script>
  <title>logging a string test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="my_wonderful_button">log a string!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing event handlers to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588040/139010

Comment: Forget about using various `onload` events, and just move your script to the bottom of the `body` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    document.getElementById("my_wonderful_button").onclick = log_a_string_plz;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sQJZY/)**

Comment: wait why? document.onload is triggered after the DOM is loaded, right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload for an explanation of the differences.